# Shell script: Check if a Directory is of YYYY_MM_DD_HH this format

Tags: shell, unix

I have a script that creates a file list of directories available in another path.
Now, I would like to do some tasks only if the Directory is of the format "YYYY_MM_DD_HH" in this file list.

My file list has following entries:

2014_04_21_01

asdf

2012_01_19_10

2010_01

Now  I would like to move the directories with names as  YYYY_MM_DD_HH  to another path. I.e., only 2014_04_21_01 & 2012_01_19_10 MUST be MOVED.

Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use bash regex pattern matching:

```
for dir in $list
do if [[ "$dir" =~ ^[0-9]{4}_[0-9]{2}_[0-9]{2}_[0-9]{2}$ ]]
   then mv "$dir" newdir/
   fi
done
```

Comment: Except for the Perl solution, all the other solutions I have tried and they produce the desired result. Thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a GNU version of `sed` on your computer, you could use it to easily parse your directory names and execute a command.

Say we have following input file:

```
2014_04_21_01
asdf
2012_01_19_10
2010_01
2012_01_19_10_09
62012_01_19_10
```

You can search for your regex with `sed` and replace it with a `mv` command as follows:

```
sed 's/^[0-9]\{4\}\(_[0-9]\{2\}\)\{3\}$/mv "&" "other_dir"/' file_list
```

will output:

```
mv "2014_04_21_01" "other_dir"    # We want to run this
asdf
mv "2012_01_19_10" "other_dir"    # and this
2010_01
2012_01_19_10_09
62012_01_19_10
```

Now if you add the (GNU `sed`) `e` option at the end of `sed` substitution (and `-n` option before `sed` script to ensure only successul substitutions are executed), the generated command will be piped into your shell:

```
sed -n 's/^[0-9]\{4\}\(_[0-9]\{2\}\)\{3\}$/mv "&" "other_dir"/e' file_list
#   ^^                                                        ^
```

I would recommand to run it first without the `e` option so as to check that `mv` commands will be properly formatted.

Answer (score 1):

Why to make separate file for file list. Just go in that directory execute following command. I have taken the destination directory as /home/newdir/

```
ls | grep [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]_[01][0-9]_[0123][0-9]_[012][0-9] | awk '{print $0" /home/newdir/"}'  | xargs mv
```

Be Careful  while working with dates. As you have mentioned that file name is in format YYYY_MM_DD_HH then we have restrictions on MM,DD and HH. If we talk about restrictions then we know how a calendar is constructed. So 9999_99_99_99 is invalid file name. It is not satisfying YYYY_MM_DD_HH.
We have to build script for restrictions or I can say whole calendar. Still working on it.

Comment: This will catch files as well as directories.  But if you were going to do this, why not:
`mv [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]_[0-9][0-9]_[0-9][0-9]_[0-9][0-9] targetdir`

Answer (score 1):

Example:

```
perl -nle 'system("mv $_ dir/year$1") if /^(\d{4})_\d\d_\d\d_\d\d/$' flist
```

would extract the year and rename dir `2014_04_21_01` to `dir/year2014`

Answer (score 1):

This single `find` command with `-regex` option should take care of this:

```
cd /base/path/of/these/dirs

find . -type d -regextype posix-egrep -regex '.*/[0-9]{4}_[0-9]{2}_[0-9]{2}_[0-9]{2}$' \
      -exec mv '{}' /dest/dir/ \;
```